# Japanese for dual flush toilet

Tags: translation

What's the Japanese for dual flush toilet, a flush toilet that allows you to choose either a large flush (大) or small flush (小)?

Google translate suggests "デュアル水洗トイレ" (katakana for "dual" plus "flush toilet"), but the [Japanese Wikipedia article on flush toilets](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B0%B4%E6%B4%97%E5%BC%8F%E4%BE%BF%E6%89%80) doesn't have "デュアル" in it, nor does the Japanese Wikipedia article on [toilets in Japan](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E4%BE%BF%E6%89%80) (a google search for オーストラリアの便所 didn't help, either). jisho.org doesn't have anything matching ["dual flush"](http://jisho.org/search/dual%20flush) or any relevant matches using [デュアル](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%83%87%E3%83%A5%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%20%23words?page=2) (and based on this search for [dual](http://jisho.org/search/dual%20%23words?page=4) there's only one katakana form for "dual").

Searching ejje for [dual flush toilet](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/Dual+flush+toilet) just supplied the English language Wikipedia article.

linguee.jp had one match for [dual flush](http://www.linguee.jp/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E-%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/search?source=auto&query=dual%20flush): "二重流し水洗トイレ", from Australia's main tourism site.

Maybe there's a semantic gap, because Japan doesn't have many single-flush toilets.

Comment: Curious to know what a search for "Australian toilet" was for. You are more likely to get pictures of old outhouse longdrops than dual-flush porcelein.

Comment: @The Wandering Coder Australia created the first dual flush toilet.

Comment: A fact that although I am aware of, makes little sense to look at in the context of Japanese toilet products. As stated in other comments, dual-flush toilets being the norm in Japan mean that most people are unaware of any Australian connection. Japanese "washlet" toilets are universally known for having bidets, however searching for French toilet would make little sense in context.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder It was only a parenthetical statement, made after talking about the Wikipedia article on toilets in Japan. Don't take it too seriously.

Comment: I didn't mean to. I just thought it an interesting thought pattern. I have never seen Australian Toilets come up in conversation in Japan. I guess I shall have to make it so. It is Australia Day after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In reality, this is not a very common topic of conversation in Japan because, as you so stated, the dual flush is just the norm here.  Every time I see/hear the system mentioned, it is mentioned by a non-Japanese person who has visited Japan.

If, however, you need a term for a possible future discussion on the topic with a Japanese-speaker, you might use one such as 「[大小]{だいしょう}[切り替え]{きりかえ}[式]{しき}」、「大小切り替えタイプ」, etc.

I could not promise that these are the most common ways to describe it as I have never actively talked about it with anyone, but I could promise that at least virtually every Japanese-speaker would understand what you are referring to if you used them.

You could say (and be completely understood) things like:

「大小切り替え式の[水洗]{すいせん}トイレ」

「日本のトイレには『大小切り替えレバー』がついています。」　レバー = lever

***Less than 1% of us would understand 「デュアル[水洗]{すいせん}トイレ」 if you trust me.***  Ask any other native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would help if you share what you need this for. If it's to convey to someone you want to purchase a toilet with both flush types "二重流し水洗トイレ" or 大小切り替えタイプ will get the message across. I'm sure any japanese person will figure out you want a toilet with both flush patterns.

If it was me I would say "大・小水洗付きトイレ" (read ”だい・しょう・すいせんつきトイレ”)

Comment: For future reference you can add furigana by enclosing the reading directly after the Kanji in curly brackets when marking up your answer.

便座 {べんざ} = 便座 + {べんざ}

Answer (score 0):

There might be somewhat of a semantic gap, most people won't ever need to use the word, discussion about toilet models would much more concerned about washlets, rather than dual flush.

It seems however that the correct form would be "デュアル水洗式トイレ" rather than "デュアル水洗トイレ" that mostly Chinese sites use, specifically with regard to this http://ja.myecom.net/english/blog/2015/028465/ and this http://www.sekaimon.com/us/71284/Toilets/151176694826/ occurrence.

I've found [one case of デュアルフラッシュ in a PDF](https://www.jpo.go.jp/shiryou/pdf/gidou-houkoku/22lavatory_wash.pdf), but this is usually the transcription of "dual flash", so not recommended